# The property of the object that the user enters

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm a beginner and I'm in the process of writing a calculator, but I ran into a problem that I have an object with Roman numbers inside (there will be 100 in total, but I wrote 5 here to shorten it).

```
const objRome = {
  I: 1,
  II: 2,
  III: 3,
  IV: 4,
  V: 5,
};
let mathCalc = prompt("mathematical sign");
```

My problem is that I need the user to enter a number (`let userInput1 = prompt("Number 1")` и `let userInput2 = prompt("Number2")`)and I need it to come out for example I + II = III.

The logic is as follows:

- I looks at the object and sees that it is 1
- II looks at the object and sees that it is 2
- 1 + 2
- result 3 looks at the object and sees that it is III
- outputs III

I tried to do stupid things and contact directly, but alas it doesn't work that way (output undefined):

```
console.log(objRome.userInput1); // undefined
const objRome = {
  I: 1,
  II: 2,
  III: 3,
  IV: 4,
  V: 5,
};
let userInput1 = prompt("number1");
let userInput2 = prompt("number2");

let mathCalc = prompt("mathematical sign")

if (!isNaN(userInput1) == true && !isNaN(userInput2) == true) {
  //arabicNum
  if (mathCalc == "+") {
    console.log((userInput1 * 1) + (userInput2 * 1))
  } else if (mathCalc == "-") {
    console.log(userInput1 - userInput2)
  } else if (mathCalc == "*") {
    console.log(userInput1 * userInput2)
  } else if (mathCalc == "/") {
    console.log(userInput1 / userInput2)
  };
} else if (!isNaN(userInput1) == false && !isNaN(userInput2) == false) {
  if (userInput1 == objRome)
};

// let x = objRome.hasOwnProperty("I");
// console.log(x);
```

Comment: I suggest to format code using the editor.

Comment: What have you tried and how did it fall short of expectations?

Comment: I tried to contact directly, check through .hasOwnProperty (but it outputs either true or false, but I need a slightly different check so that something further can be output)

Comment: What "slightly different check" do you need? Please show the code you tried, rather than your starting point.

Comment: Just a second, I'll edit the question and add my code in full

Comment: I added the code,  I want to make a fragment with Roman numbers through checking the property

Comment: The code you added has lots of syntax errors. What is `userInput1`?